# Document library not visible in Sharepoint but can be seen in mapped drive

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, assets, sharepoint-designer, sharepointdocumentlibrary

There is one folders named **companyassets** in the mapped network drive that I have created for a SharePoint 2013 website. when I try to edit/delete a file(companyassets/js/main.js) it gives error that the file is either checked out or locked. Also, I am unable to see the same document library in the SharePoint "Site Libraries and Lists"

Comment: Was the companyassets folder created using the "new folder" option in the file explorer, instead of being created as a document library through the browser interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal. This is the default behavior. On first upload of file, this file is checked-out for edit. that means : only creator can view and edit document untill he check-in the document. (when user chekin, the document can be view by all user).

If you are administrator, there is a View that display all check-out document. And you can check-in document (in list settings)

Comment: actually i cant even reach the list settings. when i try to reach http://server/Lists/companyAssets/AllItems.aspx I get page not found error

Comment: May be this View simply don't exist. When you try to browse at : server/Lists/companyAssets what append ? you have a 404

Comment: yes. but I see this folder in the mapped drive in windows explorer

Comment: Your list is probably hiden from the SharePoint UI. Try to open your site with SharePoint Designer, and you will be able to checkin your document or view more content.

Comment: In general, the document library (list who contains files) is located at : `{sitecollectionURL}/{ListName}` And the list is located at : `{sitecollectionURL}/Lists/{ListName}`. You said : your document library is located at server/Lists/companyAssets, may be the URL is wrong, try **server/companyAssets**

Comment: Thank you, I was able to edit the files from SharePoint Designer.